# boost::python でユーザ定義構造体/クラスをメンバに含む構造体/クラスにアクセスする

Tags: python, boost

こういうことをBoost::pythonを使ってやりたいです。

**C言語側**

```
struct A{
    int x;
    int y;
}
struct B{
    int id;
    A a;
}
```

**Python側**

```
b = B()
b.a.x = 0
b.a.y = 1
b.id = 25
```

Boost.pythonで試してみたところ、

```
boost::python::class_<B>("B")
    .def_readwrite("id", &B::id);
```

は動作して、上記コードスニペットでb.id = 25 にあたる部分は正常動作します。
ですが、

```
boost::python::class_<B>("B")
    .def_readwrite("a", &B::a);
```

では、b.a までは動いても、b.a.x の呼び出しができません。

おそらく、構造体/クラスのメンバ変数にユーザ定義の構造体/クラスが含まれる場合に特別な書き方があるのだろう、と思います。
書き方のポイントを教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: boost::python でクラスAの型も定義する必要があったかと思います。なお余談ですが、C++11が使える場合は pybind11 が便利で、boost への依存が不要になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。クラスAの型は単体でも使うので定義済みです。
converterを実装しなければならなさそう、というところまで掴みました。
最終的にやりたいことは商用ライブラリを手元でPythonで使うためのバインディングの開発なので、いっそのことPython層をもう一段挟んでこういう厄介な構造からおさらばしたほうが手かな、とも考えています。

pybind11でこの問題が楽になるなら試す価値はあるので、実験的に手を動かしてみます。

Answer (score 1):

python3.7 + pybind11 での実装ですが、以下のコードは動作しました。

**src/main.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

struct A{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B{
    int id;
    A a;
};

namespace py = pybind11;


PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {

  py::class_<A>(m, "A")
    .def(py::init<int, int>())
    .def_readwrite("x", &A::x)
    .def_readwrite("y", &A::y);

  py::class_<B>(m, "B")
    .def(py::init<int, A>())
    .def_readwrite("id", &B::id)
    .def_readwrite("a", &B::a);
}
```

**sample.py**

```
from example import A, B

a = A(1, 2)    
b = B(1, a)

b.a.x = 0
b.a.y = 1
b.id = 25

print(b.a.x, b.a.y, b.id)
```

[pybind11/python_example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example) の setup.py を参考にビルドしています。

```
$ pip install pybind11
$ pip install .
$ python sample.py
0 1 25
```